# Duplicate key value violates unique constraint during rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

How to avoid `Duplicate key value violates unique constraint`

i assume that `id:1` already in use, but i need to strongly setup `id`,

because i have method in `category` model

```
def iconic
  case self.id
      when 1
       smth
     ....
  end  
 end
```

my factory

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :category do
    sequence(:title) { |n| Faker::Hipster.word+"#{n}" }
    position 1
    text Faker::Lorem.sentence
    image File.open(Rails.root.join('test', 'assets', 'images', 'banners', (1..6).to_a.sample.to_s+'.png'))

  end
end

Failure/Error: c1 = create(:category, id: 1)

 ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique:
   PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "categories_pkey"
   DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) already exists.
```

Comment: Whats the actual use case?

Answer (score 1):

Yes the problem is that you are trying to create multiple records with same value of `id` attribute, which is not allowed. It should always be unique.

The actual problem what i think is your model code which is dependent on `id` of the object.

```
def iconic
  case self.id
    when 1
     smth
     ....
  end  
end
```

This is not a good practice to write logic based on `id` attribute because when you can't make sure that the same id will be assigned to same object everytime you populate database. Instead you should use some other unique attributes like `slug`, `email`, `username`, whatever suits your model. So, you should modify you model logic like this:

```
def iconic
  case self.slug_or_any_other_unique_field
    when 'expected_value_of_above_field'
      smth
      ....
  end  
end
```